# Небезопасный iframe (http) на безопасном (https) сайте

Tags: iframe, https, ssl

Сегодня перевел сайт на `https`, но возникли некоторые сложности с `IFRAME`.

Одна из страниц сайта, с помощью `iframe`, подгружает контент другого сайта, у которого нет сертификата `SSL`, и который работает по `http`, но из-за того что на моем сайте установлен `https - iframe` не загружается.

`Firefox Firebug` говорит: *"Заблокирована загрузка смешанного активного содержимого"*

Подскажите, есть ли возможность подгрузить небезопасный сайт на безопасный с помощью `iframe` или других средств ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты доверяешь содержимому сайта о котором идёт речь то можно попробовать проксировать его через свой веб-сервер, т.е. запрос будет посылаться на твой хост, а веб-сервер будет проксировать запрос на второй сайт и возвращать его ответ.

В apache для этого используется директива ProxyPass, в nginx используется proxy_pass.

Пример для nginx:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...
    location = /foreign-iframe {
        proxy_pass              http://foreign.site.ru/test.asp;
        proxy_read_timeout      30;
        keepalive_timeout       60;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;

        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-SERVER-PORT   $server_port;
        proxy_set_header        X-FORWARDED-FOR $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-ARGS          $args;
        proxy_set_header        X-REQUEST-URI   $request_uri;
    }
}
```